# Difference between "likely" and "potential"

Tags: meaning, difference

> “Evidence of Use (EoU) is a type of analysis designed to protect the
>   IP and related interests of patent holders and investors. Its primary
>   goals are to identify products, processes, or services in the
>   marketplace that potentially infringe on the patent in question and to
>   evaluate the strength of the patent assertion campaign……Besides
>   identifying **likely and potential infringers**, EoU can also give an
>   indication of a patent’s future potential, provide information
>   necessary for the creation of a sales or licensing agreement, and help
>   patent owners build a viable and sustainable R&D plan.”
>
> From https://www.legaladvantage.net/patent-search/evidence-of-use/

What is the difference between "likely" and "potential" here? Does “potential” mean the entity will grow to become an infringer? How is it different from “likely”?

I originally asked the question here https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/likely-and-potential-infringers.3613204/#post-18401117, but was still confused. Could you help me?

> Likely:
>
> 1  used to indicate the chance that something will happen
>
> 2  seeming to be true : BELIEVABLE
>
> 3  always used before a noun : seeming to be right or suited for a
>   purpose
>
> http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/likely
>
> Potential:
>
> capable of becoming real : POSSIBLE
>
> http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/potential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, I would say that the author is using the two in order to mean two different levels of likelihood:

A 'likely' infringer is one who has (lets say) a more than 50% chance of infringing.

A 'potential' infringer is therefore one who is less likely, but still has the 'motive and means' to do so.

(Not the most obvious bit of English - quite poor really unless it has already been defined earlier in the document.)

Answer (score 0):

I do believe this is the case;

**Likely:**

> Possibility of anything to happen based on some actual proof.

**Potential:**

> A slight chance of anything to happen and has no proof.

other wise we won't be able to say:

> He has proved his **potential**. Now he is **likely** to be chosen as a quarterback.